# Backspace key from edit screen in review exits the review queue

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, edits, review

This is a pretty simple one. Pressing the backspace key (my preferred method of going back a page), while on the edit page of a review, leaves the review queue.

The expected behavior is that I will return to the review I was just on, instead of exiting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually the case for all inline-editing on the site, not just via review.

While perhaps unexpected, I'm not sure there's a straightforward solution. Most of the page stays intact, while only the post is replaced with the edit UI. As for whether this constitutes a new browser history state, it seems borderline.

Comment: Fair enough. It'd be tricky to add a new browser state - and after all, it's just one key. I'll change.